# My logger keeps getting destructed while I am trying to log errors and exceptions

Tags: php

I am just now switching back to PHP after enterprise open-source Java development for three years.  Now I am tasked with updating our platform for better logging.

I now understand better how the PHP object lifecycle regarding when objects are garbage collected and have trapped my problem.  I am trying to invoke the logger after its already been destructed, when a fatal error occurs.  My question is, how do I fix this?  How can I stop an object from being destroyed until the end of the request?

Ideally I would like to keep this logger around in memory like I would in Java but is that even possible with PHP?  Is there anything shared between two different threads or requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PHP, each request is processed by a different process -- which means you quite cannot keep some object arround between requests *(you could serialize it and store it in a file or something like that, and un-serialize it when another requests comes ; but that's not really the way things are generally done)*

This means each time your PHP script receives a request, you have to re-instanciate your logger.

Now, if you want to use your logger from several different classes/methods/functions in the same script, you have to know that variables are not global "by default" in PHP : a variable declared outside of a function is not accessible from inside a function, unless you said so using the [global keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global).

In this kind of situation, when you want one and only one instance of a specific class (your logger) available from anywhere in your application, people often use the [Singleton Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

It'll allow to use something like this :

```
My_Logger_Class::log('blah');
```

From any portion of your code, and the `log` method will deal with :

- instanciating the class if there was not already one existing instance
- the actual logging

And, yes, the first time this method is called for one HTTP request, it'll have to re-open the log file *(if logging to a file)*.

As a sidenote : there are already some existing great logging components, like [`PEAR::Log`](http://pear.php.net/package/Log) or [`Zend_Log`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.html).

Maybe using one of those might help you spend less time re-inventing some wheel ?